# Problem during Plowshare's installation

Tags: package-management, ppa, 14.10

Today i tried to install **Plowshare** on Ubuntu Server **14.10**, as written in [Plowshare's documentation](https://code.google.com/p/plowshare/wiki/Readme4#Download_&_Install).

So, i added the Plowshare's repository with this command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:plowsharepackagers/ppa
```

All was well.

Next, i updated my system, but I found that **this PPA returns 404 errors**, so the installation went wrong.

Is there an **other way** to install it?

Comment: What do you mean by 'invalid'?  The package [shows up clearly in their PPA](https://launchpad.net/~plowsharepackagers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages) as a 'Trusty' package.

Comment: Here's the log of **apt-get update**: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9030183/

Comment: Are you on 14.04 Trusty, or 14.10 Utopic?  The 404 line there is because apt is trying to find Utopic packages in the PPA, which are nonexistant, instead of Trusty packages.  I'm assuming Utopic 14.10 because of the other apt-get lines.

Comment: I bought a VPS from Ovh, i think it's Utopic...

Comment: Maury, OK, that's 14.10, not 14.04.  I'm going to tweak your question and then answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, i didn't think that OVH distributed the version 14.10

Comment: that's fine.  Note I made a pretty detailed answer below to try and resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you initially stated you were on 14.04 LTS.  This is not the case based on your `apt-get` output you linked in comments, and your system is on Utopic 14.10.

Secondly, the PPA they are referring to is for Trusty 14.04, and does not publish packages for Utopic 14.10.  That is why the PPA is erroring out.

There's two ways we can address this:

1. Manually download the package and install it, or
2. Build the software from source (if they provide code somewhere), or
3. Tell the system to look for Trusty for that PPA instead of Utopic.

When you do the commands listed in the `plowshare` readme, they are expecting a Trusty system, so they give you the PPA with their Trusty package versions in it.

Ultimately, I do not recommend manual downloading of the package, and unless you know what you're doing, I don't advise building the software by hand, so we'll explore option #3 instead.

You'll need the command line for all these commands.

1. `cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d/`
2. Do an `ls` and look for a file that is named `plowsharepackagers-ppa-utopic.list`.  There may be a `.list.save` file too, in which case lets delete the save file (`sudo rm plowsharepackagers-ppa-utopic.list.save`)
3. Lets first move this file to a different name - as we want to make a note it's going to seek out Trusty instead of Utopic.  `sudo mv plowsharepackagers-ppa-utopic.list plowsharepackagers-ppa-trusty.list`
4. Open up that file in your favorite command line text editor.  I use `nano`.  `sudo nano plowsharepackagers-ppa-trusty.list`.  The file should look a little like this:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/plowsharepackagers/ppa/ubuntu utopic main
#deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/plowsharepackagers/ppa/ubuntu utopic main
```

5. Lets edit the file such that `utopic` is replaced by `trusty`.  It should then look like this:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/plowsharepackagers/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/plowsharepackagers/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
```

6. Save the file, and then exit the text editor.
7. Run the following commands ***in this order***:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install plowshare4
```

8. Plowshare should now be installed.  Enjoy.